# Grails - How do I save one class instance from a different controller?

Tags: grails, controller, save, grails-domain-class

I have a list of input coming in from `_form.gsp`. i.e. `English, Science, Math, Music` along with other `student` information. When `submit` button is clicked, it goes to the `studentController` `save` method.

I'd like to add `Music` to the `course` database if it is not found.

This is what I have right now.

```
def save(Student studentInstance) {
....
    def courseInputList = params.course.tokenize(', ')
        for (item in courseInputList){  
            def courseID = Course.findByCourseLike(item)
            StudnetCourse.link(studentInstance,courseID)
        }
....
}
```

I have an autocomplete, so the user will start typing and a list will pop up to choose from.

I added `if (courseID == null) { }` statement right under `def courseID = Course.findByCourseLike(item)` but I don't have any success with saving conditions. I tried ``` redirect``forward``new Course(item).save flush:true ``` etc. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried with `failOnError: true` to see if there is error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use domain's dynamic method : **findOrCreateBy*** . In your case it will be like:

```
def courseInputList = params.course.tokenize(', ')

for (item in courseInputList){  
        def courseID = Course.findOrCreateByCourseLike(item)
        StudnetCourse.link(studentInstance,courseID)
}
```

More info you can find here : http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrCreateBy.html

Comment: Great, it worked. I needed the course saved so I used `findOrSaveBy`. Thank you.